# Удаление информации из таблицы базы данных Access через c# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

При нажатии на кнопку отвечающую за удаление информации из базы данных Access выдаётся ошибка System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Ошибка синтаксиса (пропущен оператор) в выражении запроса 'ID материала = 16'."
Код кнопки

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count != 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ОДну строку!", "Ошибка");
                return;
            }
            int index = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;

            if (dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Не все данные введены", "Ошибка");
                return;
            }

            string IDматериала = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();


            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=BD.mdb";

            OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            dbConnection.Open();
            string query = "Delete From Материалы Where ID материала = " + IDматериала;
            OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, dbConnection);

            if (dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1)
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка заполнения", "Ошибка");
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Данные удалены", "Успех");
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
            }
            dbConnection.Close();
        }

        
    }
```

Comment: У вас действительно существует столбец под названием "ID материала"? Я про пробел между словами. Пробовали внутри базы прописывать этот запрос на удаление? Внутри БД нормально удаляет или тоже ошибку выводит? Если запрос, как вы считаете, создан корректно, отредактируйте ваш вопрос и добавьте в него структуру вашей таблицы "Материалы"

Comment: Все сложные названия столбцов надо экранировать - хороший стиль написания запросов в T-SQL. В Вашем случае [ID материала]  ну и прочее так же